# Why does swipe left not work for Jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have the following code that tries to detect swipes left and right:

```
    $('#my_view').bind('pageinit', function() {
        $( '#my_view' ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#myItem", function( event ) {
            var listitem = $( this ),
            dir = event.type === "swipeleft" ? "left" : "right";
            console.log("Detected swipe!!!! " + dir);
        }); 
    });
```

However this only detects the right swipe and never detects a left swipe, can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a fiddle and it seems to work fine

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/kNd8s/)**

Maybe for the pageinit, use $(document).on:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#my_view", function(){   
    $('#my_view').on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#myItem li", function( event ){
        alert(event.type);

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that but I am afraid that is not working either, is there some gotcha's surrounding this kind of behaviour with JQuery mobile?

Comment: Not that I know of. Is the fiddle not working for you?

Comment: Fiddle is but its not working in my application at all, only swipe right is detected